# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: trying to add in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Attached is an error readout I've been getting. I've added the proper frameworks in my linked libraries, I've checked my target memberships for implementation files, I just don't know why I'm constantly getting the error below.

[image]
My project was building fine the other day, and when I opened up my computer the next morning and tried to build, I was given these error messages. I messed around with the architecture in my build settings, as per advice from other stack overflow questions, and it brought the number of errors from 20 down to 5. Still totally confused on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have not added `AssetsLibrary` in your project.

Add that library in "Link Binary With Libraries" your error will be gone.

Comment: That helped with the AssetsLibrary architecture error but the other ones still remain: CABasicAnimation, _kUTTypeMovie and the linker error.

Comment: I just had to add the quartzcore framework and also mobilecoreservices